# FileBeat Multiline Regular Expression

Tags: regex, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I have a log pattern as below, for which I am trying to create a regular expression that matches (the whole pattern).The lines have double spacing between them.How can i write a regex which captures double spacing

```
02/21/2022 08:48:41 AM com.myClass ERROR:  com.MyException: The id '-1' is not valid for an object of type 'Result Type' (50) 
com.MyException: The id '-1' is not valid for an object of type 'Result Type' (50)

    at com.myClass.createResultType(Native Method)

    at com.myClass.getResultTableForResult(MyClass.java:1172)

    at com.myClass.getResultFromUDSRPnlWrapper(MyClass.java:508)

    at com.myClass.loadDataSet(MyClass.java:143)

    at com.myClass.calculate(MyClass.java:166)
```

The below config is not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
  multiline.type: pattern
  multiline.pattern: '^\n[[:space:]]'
  multiline.negate: false
  multiline.match: after
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^\s*$|^[[:space:]] - filters the above pattern